# Which comparision operator is *= 

Tags: sql, database, comparison, powerbuilder, sqlanywhere

In Powerbuilder datawindow I a select query contains:

```
(~"abc~".~"year~" = ~"xyz~".~"year~" ) and  
( ~"abc~".~"number~" *= ~"xyz~".~"number~" )
```

I understand the equal operator is used in first line, but what does *= mean? Thanks.

Comment: In SQL Server `*=` is an outer join. Could be the case in SQL Anywhere as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its an Outer join, Check the section "Join syntax and join processing" in this [Documentation](http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/asg1250e/ptoptab.pdf)